# Error in lhs - rhs : argumento não-numérico para operador binário

Tags: r

Estou tentando rodar a função ...

```
m.ex=nls(dados$var1~y0*exp(r*dados$dias), data=dados, start = list(y0=10,r=0.005));m.ex
```

** ... no conjunto de dados:**

> str(dados)

```r
'data.frame':   24 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dias: int  1 1 1 10 10 10 20 20 20 30 ...
 $ var1: chr  "2.1" "4.8" "3.7" "6" ...
```

ao executar a função, aparece o erro:

`Error in lhs - rhs : argumento não-numérico para operador binário`

O que pode estar errado na função?

Obrigada a quem puder responder e dar uma solução!!

Comment: `var1` tá como character, sendo q ele devia estar com algum formato numérico. Tente botar um `dados$var1 <- as.numeric(dados$var1)` antes do nls

Comment: Se não resolver, recomendo editar a pergunta com o resultado de `dput(head(dados))`. Que assim outras pessoas podem reproduzir e ajudar na solução.

Comment: Muito obg!! Deu certo!